# Gathering data with VBA from yet to be created worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have been asked to create summary worksheets for excel files that I don't populate. These are 'monthly' excel files with the worksheets 'usually' named as to the week commencing date. I say 'usually' as a spelling mistake might creep in or such that wont allow the sheet names to be predicted in advance of their creation. The worksheet wont be created until the week in question has begun.

What I am trying to do, though struggling with, is create some VBA code to copy a number of cells and ranges from each worksheet to a summary worksheet which will be hidden. The worksheets all follow the same formatting, the main info being: A1 as the weekstart date, O4 to R4 as 4 summary column headers and N5 to N30 as username info. O5 to R30 then has counts in them depending on the data within the worksheet.

I want to create some code that copies the weekstart date (A1) alongside each username that is not blank (N5:N30) and the values after in the corresponding row. As the column headers in O4 to R4 dont change these can stay static on the summary sheet.

Afraid I dont know too much about vba. I guess I would use Worksheets.Count to find the number of worksheets? Was going to modify the code on [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sheet-index.htm) but I dont know how to ensure each row of data goes on a new line in the summary worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

use the ozgrid example but make this alteration:

`.Range("A1").`

to

`.Range("A" & l).`

then amend your original post with further questions + the actual code you are using.

Answer (score -1):

I have amended ozgrid code with the following which may be more or less relevant to your query. If you can rephrase your query into a more task1, task2 way, it will then be easy to change the below script into something you want.

The below script just work as a module instead of a worksheet event which is easier to control, just create a sub module and copy paste it there then run it or you can also create a button on the worksheet to run, using developper tab and choose form or activex button linked to the macro SplitWs.

```
Sub SplitWs()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

i = 1

    With wSheet
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
        .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
    End With


    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wSheet.Name Then
            i = i + 1
                With wSheet
                    .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:="Back to Index"
                End With

                wSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wSheet.Cells(i, 1), Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

I also change the 'l' variable into 'i' which is easier to read.

Hope it will be of help, else comment with the things to amend.

Pascal

http://multiskillz.tekcities.com